# How to make RHEL 6 to boot in Text-mode?

Tags: fedora, rhel, boot, grub-legacy

I am using RHEL 6.4 on a HP-Z620 Workstation.Whenever this machine starts up, it comes up with Graphics Mode e.g. Splash Screen,Red Hat Logo etc.

But I want my machine to start in Text Mode.
e.g. I want my machine showing all Kernel Messages(saying which services are being started).

Previous versions of RHEL provided an option

```
Press I for interactive startup
```

But this version does not provide that.
How to get back that feature?

Answer (score 2):

Edit /etc/grub.conf back it up first though.

Remove rhgb and quiet

Reboot.

Or just hit the down arrow key when the system boots to switch to no splash.

Comment: fwiw "quiet" just causes the kernel to not print out as much information. Removal of "rhgb" is sufficient for removing he graphical boot splash.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is to disable this through plymouth:

```
plymouth-set-default-plugin text
/usr/libexec/plymouth/plymouth-update-initrd
```

If you're interested in more about plymouth check out the references to it below. It's what powers the bootsplash for Red Hat based distros.

#### References

- [RHEL6 - disable the tiered-progress bar during boot](https://superuser.com/questions/257888/rhel6-disable-the-tiered-progress-bar-during-boot)
- [freedesktop.org - Software/Plymouth](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth)
- [wikipedia - Plymouth (software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth_%28software%29)
- [Plymouth Launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/plymouth)